# tool to create views automatically when the limit is reached

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold

my question is: is there a tool for SPO or exists a way to create views automatically when you reach the view limits? Per view you have a limitation of 5000 documents.

If doesn't exists. Is there an event that I could capture in the creation of the document? and if that document reaches the limit I can create another view when I'm uploading or creating that document?

Comment: This can help https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do once you go over 5000 items other than deleting items to get under the thresh hold, so it behooves you to plan accordingly ahead of time if a list or library is going to go over the thresh hold.

Create indexed columns and create filtered views based off of those indexed columns to return result sets below 5000 items and you'll be ok.

Comment: We are trying to plan ahead, but there are system connecting to SharePoint that in some cases will upload more than 5000 documents

Comment: In SPO, you can't dump it and fix it later like you can on prem. It takes careful planning ahead of time so you don't have problems. You should be able to reliably set up indexed columns ahead of time and then create filtered views as needed. If you don't set up the indexes first, you can't do that once you go over the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write a Remote Event Receiver that detects when a document is added, checks how many documents are in the library, checks what views exist, then create a new view in batches of 5000 (e.g. `ID >= 5000 && ID < 10000), since ID is an indexed column.

Still, finding more meaningful ways to group and filter data on different indexed columns would be a better approach.